# how to load data based on id using Vue js and Laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a table called candidate_profiles with the following columns:

```
'user_id', 'photo_id', 'resume_id', 'video_one_id', 'video_two_id', 
'video_three_id', 'date_of_birth', 'employment_type', 'experience','skills'
```

I have a page `/employer/search` that displays all of the profiles from that table. I'm using `paginate` to display 5 records per page. At the bottom I have a 'Load More' button, when clicked another 5 (or less) profiles appear. If there are anymore you will still see the 'Load More' button otherwise it will disappear.

This is how I'm fetching the data.

EmployerSearchController.php file:

```
public function search()
{
    $candidateProfile = CandidateProfile::orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->paginate(5);

    $user = User::all()->where('id', $candidateProfile->first()->user_id);

    $videoOne = Video::all()->where('id', $candidateProfile->first()->video_one_id);
    $videoTwo = Video::all()->where('id', $candidateProfile->first()->video_two_id);
    $videoThree = Video::all()->where('id', $candidateProfile->first()->video_three_id);
    $resumes = Resume::all()->where('id', $candidateProfile->first()->resume_id);
    $photos = Photo::all()->where('id', $candidateProfile->first()->photo_id);

    return response()->json(array($candidateProfile, $videoOne, $videoTwo, $videoThree, $resumes, $photos, $user), 200);

}
```

And this is how I'm assigning the data into variable and creating the Load More feature in my front end Vue js code:

```
methods: {
        loadCandidateProfileData: async function() {
            try {
                const response = await employerService.loadCandidateProfileData();
                this.resumes = response.data[4];
                this.video_one = response.data[1];
                this.video_two = response.data[2];
                this.video_three = response.data[3];
                this.photos = response.data[5];
                this.users = response.data[6];

                this.candidateProfiles = response.data[0].data;

                if (response.data[0].current_page < response.data[0].last_page) {
                    this.moreExists = true;
                    this.nextPage = response.data[0].current_page + 1;
                } else {
                    this.moreExists = false;
                }

                // console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data, undefined, 4));

            } catch (error) {
                this.$toast.error("Some error occurred, please refresh!");
            }
        },
```

The problem is this because I'm fetching the Videos, resume and photo from their own respective tables, I'm not getting the right information because it's not querying the right id.

If all of the data was coming from 1 table I wouldn't have this problem, but I'm fetching data from multiple tables.

How can I get the right data for each candidate_profile record in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a relationship on the CandidateProfile model. See here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships. So for example with user you can have in you CandidateProfile  model

```
public function user()
{
    // You can choose the relationship that best suits your need for the users table
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

and when querying you can get that relationship by

```
 $candidateProfile = CandidateProfile::with('users')->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->paginate(5);
```

then you can access those users by

```
$candidateProfile->users
```

The same can be applied to your other table relations (video, resumes, photos).

Then you can just pass `$candidateProfile` back through to your vue js

Comment: Question in my candidate_profiles table I have video_one_id, video_two_id, video_three_id. When I make relationship I can only specify one foreign key. Is there a way to specify multiple foreign keys? Or how can I get all 3 ids in one relationship? Something like:
```
public function users()
{
    // You can choose the relationship that best suits your need for the users table
    return $this->belongsToMany(Video::class, 'video_one_id', 'video_two_id', 'video_three_id');
}```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Not like that no. You will have to do separate relation for that to work. So you will have functions `videoOne`, `VideoTwo`, `VideoThree`. I'm not sure how you have your tables set up but if videoOne can have many candidateProfile and vise versa you may want to use pivot tables to store the relations between the two

Comment: As mentioned at the top of my post inside candidate_profiles table I have ```'user_id', 'photo_id', 'resume_id', 'video_one_id', 'video_two_id', 
'video_three_id', 'date_of_birth', 'employment_type', 'experience','skills'```
I have a Users table with 'name', 'email', 'password'. A user can have only one Candidate Profile associated with it. Knowing this is my structure what kind of relationship do you think I need? Is this a One to Many, Many to Many, One to Many polymorphic or Many to Many polymorphic or something else?

Comment: If a user can only have one candidate profile then the relationship will be a one to one. The link I supplied in my answer provides some good examples for each relationship that should help clear things up

Comment: Okay thanks, bottom line is I need pivot table right?

Comment: Yeah, it'll be a good next step. Right now you are getting 3 videos but what if you wanted to include more? Currently you would have to add another column but with a pivot table you can just add a new row into there with no change to code.

Comment: Thank you my friend!

Comment: Sorry, I'm still very confused. I created a pivot table between the candidate_profiles table and the videos table called candidate_profile_video. Inside of this table I created 2 columns ```candidate_profile_id, video_id```. But am I supposed to add ```'video_one_id', 'video_two_id', 'video_three_id'``` instead of video_id or on top of video_id? And what should the values be? And finally I created a Pivot model called CandidateProfileVideo which extends the pivot class. But right now there's nothing in the model. Did I miss anything else?

Comment: No worries, you are pretty much there. You just need to add three rows in your pivot table, one for each video id with the same candidate profile id. You don't need to add anything to your pivot model, in fact you might not even need it, when using a belongsToMany relationship laravel can work out by itself what table to use.

Comment: So it seems to be working, I have only two columns in the pivot table. The only thing is when a user creates a candidate_profile and uploads his videos, I will need to insert that data or the ids of the candidate_profile and of the video into the pivot table. It actually seems to be working. I'm a little scared lol

Comment: Haha, don't worry about that. Laravel is very good with these sort of things with [attach/detach](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: Hey sorry. What id do I need in between the brackets in my attach method? I want to do this $candidateProfile->save()->attach($videoId) but I don't know where $videoId comes from. They had this in the docs. And you're saying this will insert the 3 video id's into the pivot table?

Comment: hey, don't worry. So in the laravel example I gave you it shows the relationship being the `roles`, this is the function relationship to the roles table in the user model. For you it'll be the new relationship for videos you made before for the candidateProfile model. The example then continues to attach the id of the role which creates the row in the pivot table, for you it'll just be the video id.

Comment: How do I get the video id though? Do I have to do something like this? ```Video::findById($id)``` It's a little trickier because I'm building an SPA and using Vue js for my front end and Vue-Router for routing.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can help with this one. If you've created a candidate profile along side creating videos then you will have the ids already. With `Video::findById($id)` id is all you need, you don't need to fetch the video.